# related to permalinks in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

how i give permalinks to internal links of pages in wordpress
for example 
web portal services `<a href="?page_id=411">24/7 urgent support</a>`,
i want to display page name instead of page when user hover the internal link

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I understand your question, but you should first have a look here [Permalinks in wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks)
If what you want is to simply display text on hover, the text that shows up on hover is in the html Title attribute. For example `<a href="link" title="textonhover`">
You can place this in the Title attribute to generate it: `<?php echo get_the_title(ID) ?>`